# Custom opencart admin page doesn't appear

Tags: php, model-view-controller, opencart, opencart-module

i've create a custom admin page for my opencart panel. If I try to run route index.php?route=report/remarketing, system will log out instead of display page!

here's code:

controller

```
 class ControllerReportRemarketing extends Controller {
    public function index()
    {
    $template="report/remarketing.tpl";
    $this->load->language('report/remarketing');
    $this->load->model('report/remarketing');
    $this->template = ''.$template.'';
    $this->data['record'] = 'test';

    $this->children = array(
        'common/header',
        'common/footer'
    );
    $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
   }
}
```

model (have no methods)

```
class ModelReportRemarketing extends Model {
}
```

view

```
<?php echo $header; ?>
   <div id="content">
      <?php echo $record; ?>
   </div>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

Also i've setting access permission to user in User Groups

Comment: I've tried this code and its working without any issue in version `1.5.6.4`. If your model doesn't have any methods then why are you loading it in your controller file.

Comment: Problem is the same also if I remove model loading from controller!

Comment: have you modified any core files? Because i have tried the same and its working fine without any error.

Comment: probably, because I've inherited this project. If I try to force login, route return me "permission denied", although permission are setting correctly on user groups menu...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the old version opencart's code, here is the example for opencart version 2.0.2.0:

First, creat 'remarketing.php' under admin\language\english\report, add below content:

```
<?php
// Heading
$_['heading_title']    = 'Marketing Report';
```

Second, modify 'remarketing.php' under admin\controller\report as below

```
<?php
class ControllerReportRemarketing extends Controller{ 
    public function index(){
        // displayed text import
        $this->load->language('report/remarketing');

        // get header and footer
        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();
        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('common/dashboard', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL')
        );
        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('extension/feed', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL')
        );
        $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');
        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');

        // the model, need not to import
        // $this->load->model('report/remarketing');

        // testing
        $data['record'] = 'test';

        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view("report/remarketing.tpl", $data));
    }
}
?>
```

Last, modify 'remarketing.tpl' under admin\view\template\report

```
<?php echo $header; ?><?php echo $column_left; ?>
<div id="content">
  <div class="page-header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
      <ul class="breadcrumb">
        <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid"><?php echo $record; ?></div>
</div>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

Comment: I'm using old version code because I have old version of opencart. However still not work!

Comment: Could you attach the opencart version in your question? Also the tag 'opencart 2.x' should not be add. It has big difference between the old and new version...These codes should not work on the old version